# Create conditional in view based upon object attribute?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a person checkmarks the boolean `:someday` how can we trigger the conditional?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge, html: { data: { modal: true } })  do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box :someday %> # If checkmarked show first condition else show second condition
<% if :someday == true %> # How to Write this line?
  <%= link_to 'Visit London', create_challenge_path(challenge: {name: 'Visit London', categorization: 'adventure', category: 'goal'}), class: "featured-challenge" %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "challenge-button")  do %>
    Save
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Use javascript to show/remove elements based on selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user checks the checkbox, you want to show `<%= link_to 'Visit London', create_challenge_path(challenge: {name: 'Visit London', categorization: 'adventure', category: 'goal'}), class: "featured-challenge" %>`, otherwise you want to show `<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "challenge-button")  %>`, correct?

I assume that 'Save' button will be visible all the time, and I assume that default state of your checkbox is 'false'.

You can hide `.featured-challenge` from the screen, and than check in jQuery if the checkbox is checked:

```
.featured-challenge { display: none; }
```

Somewhere in your JS (featured-challenge.js maybe):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        $(".featured-challenge").toggle();
    });
});
```